# Draw more objects in browser

Tags: jquery

I try to draw two images in the browser. I have this code fragment. But I only see one image

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Cars</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
    <script>


        $(document).ready(function () {

            var Car = function (x, y) {
                this.x = x;
                this.y = y;
            };
            var drawCar = function (car) {
                var carHtml = $('#carImage');
                var carElement = $(carHtml);
                carElement.css({
                    position: "absolute",
                    left: car.x,
                    top: car.y
                });
                $("body").append(carElement);
            };

            var tesla = new Car(20, 20);
            var nissan = new Car(100, 200);

            drawCar(tesla);
            drawCar(nissan);          

        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <img src="_images/car.png" id="carImage" />   

</body>
</html>
```

But I only see one image in the browser.

How to show two images?

Thank you

Update post. I have changed the code. Thank you

You mean Like this. For the first way: But I only see one image then. So how to change the code? Thank you. Nice

```
<script>


        $(document).ready(function () {           
            var Car = function (x, y) {
                this.x = x;
                this.y = y;
            };
            var drawCar = function (car) {
                //var carHtml = $('#carImage');
                var imgTag = $('<img src="_images/car.png" id="carImage" />')
                imgTag.appendTo('body');


                var carElement = $(carHtml);
                carElement.css({
                    position: "absolute",
                    left: car.x,
                    top: car.y
                });              

                //$("body").append(carElement);
            };

            var tesla = new Car(20, 20);
            var nissan = new Car(100, 200);



                drawCar(tesla);
                drawCar(nissan);           

        });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

## First Way

Both of your images are drawing into the same image tag. You should create an image tag then append the image tag to body. Inside your draw car function, remove your logic to select the image you've already declared with this, which will append a new image every time your function runs.

```
var imgTag = $('<img src="_images/car.png" id="carImage" />')
imgTag.appendTo('body');
```

You can also remove the declaration you have in your body.

## Second Way

You could try cloning the element you want to copy into your document:

```
            var drawCar = function (car) {
            var carHtml = $('#carImage');
            var carElement = $(carHtml);
            carElement.css({
                position: "absolute",
                left: car.x,
                top: car.y
            });
            $("body").append(carElement.clone());
        };
```

Comment: Thank you. The clone method works. But what do you mean with your first way. I have updated the post. Thank you